# I just got crushed by a moderator

Tags: support

I would like to know if the other mods feel he was abusing his power.

This is the relevant question: [How do you score pork skin?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7625/how-do-you-score-pork-skin)

If I was out of line, I will quietly go away. If not, I'd like to know what the rationale was for:

1) deleting my answer

2) docking me 100 reputation

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: You are now uncrushed.

Comment: @hobodave: Thank you; I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hi Dave. I was just about to email you.

The answer was deleted because it was noise. It didn't answer the question, and should have been a comment. The comment thread that was going on in that answer belonged on meta as well.

When I tried deleting it, it kept showing as open on my screen. I didn't realize you were reopening it; I wasn't even aware that was possible. I tried flagging it as Spam to see if that would keep it closed, but I honestly had no idea that would cause a 100 point rep deduction.

I stand by my decision to delete the answer. However, I apologize profusely for the reputation deduction, it was not appropriate, and was a complete mistake on my part.

I'm trying to see if someone on the team can do anything to address this.

Comment: I really, honestly, seriously don't care about the reputation reduction, so don't kill yourself fixing it. It just struck me as vindictive. I got the impression I'd been anonymized for speaking my mind. I don't understand the deletion. Crap answers should be voted down, not deleted by someone other than the owner. If a thread should be directed to meta, then a comment to that effect would do, in my opinion. Sorry, not being hostile or trolling, just puzzled.

Comment: LOL. I'm a Scholar for 'I just got crushed by a moderator.'

Comment: @Dave: I have emailed the team. I wasn't upset by your answer, and I wasn't intending to be vindictive. I apologize for coming across that way. Bad/Wrong answers are voted down, and not deleted. However, answers that are not actually answers are deleted fairly frequently.

Comment: @Dave: Also, thank you for taking this very well. I feel rather stupid and embarrassed for the way I went about this.

Comment: Heh... I wondered about that - the answer wasn't all that funny (I'd have gone for "Have you tried a meat shop?") but it certainly wasn't *offensive*. Hobodave, next time you might consider just deleting the (increasingly off-topic) comments and redirecting the discussion to Meta.

Comment: Dude, if you're genuinely trying to make this site a better place, I'm in your corner; but, a gentle slap is better than a nuclear weapon. I'm of the opinion that the community should decide what stays and what goes. I have no hard feelings.

Comment: @Knives: *wasn't all that funny* !!! Now I'm offended :)

Comment: @Dave, it was quite funny, but the funnies belong in the comments, not in the answers.  I think if you'd have made that a comment to the question you'd have got a few upvotes, but as an answers, as @hobodave said, it just adds noise.  Nothing vindictive meant though, just trying to keep the Q&A aspect of the site clean.

Comment: @Sam Holder: I understand; getting voted down wasn't the issue, it was the summary deletion and rep loss I had a problem with. Given that it was unannounced, it came across poorly on my end.